# Interaction between levels of abstraction

Tags: oop, abstraction

Can lower-level abstractions be dependent on higher-level abstractions?
let's say i have a method named `getAudioFileInfo(id)` which should get some information about audio file with specified id from server. And list of required information is provided by higher abstraction level interface. Is it right choise to call this method inside getAudioFileInfo? Or will be better to pass the list of required information as argument?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to pass the list down the lower-level function, or split the lower-level function in more focused functions that return only one info value each one, and then assemble the result at higher-level functions.

But also consider that this does not mean you should make several requests to the server for each datum, as the requests may be expensive. So maybe you get all the data, but return the relevant only. And this makes more sense with first option.

In general ask for things in same layer or in the next lower layer, and give them what they need. See what I wrote [here](http://www.progmatico.com/en/programming-articles/software-architecture/) in Layered architecture.